# Posting code written in C language

Tags: support, markdown, code

How do I put in a block of C code into my posts?
Is there some kind of formatting trick in the textarea of the post that needs to be done in order for it to show up properly?

Comment: asking clear question does not easy make

Comment: Yoda? Is it you?

Answer (score 5):

```
int main() 
{
    printf("please clarify what you mean");
    return 0;
}
```

Or more specifically, you just indent with 4 spaces, or hit the "Code Sample" button, or press `[Ctrl]`+`[K]`.

Comment: Segmentation fault.

Comment: You forgot the newline, and using a variadic function such as printf() without a prototype in scope leads to undefined behaviour; using puts() avoids those problems.